# Nginx as proxy : how to exclude specific folder under https but not under http

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, nginx-config

I can rewrite some specific http folders to https folders, but i can't rewrite all https except these specific folders from https to http; i'm stuck in a loop

Using NGinx 1.12 as a proxy, handling both http and https

i have one server section to handle http 80 and one server section to handle https (i know they can be together in the same section).

both of them are beginning that way 
`location / {
        proxy_pass`

`server {
    listen 80;`
i have 
`location ~ ^/(xxx|yyy|zzz)/.*$ {
        rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$uri permanent;
    }`
and anytime i'm in http, it is redirecting to https fine for the xxx,yyy and zzz folders. so far, so good.

but under `server {
    listen 443 ssl;`
, i would like to redirect everything except the xxx,yyy,zzz folder to go back to http.

I did try to do the reverse in the https section meaning :
`location / {
        rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$uri permanent;
    }`
and 
`location ~ ^/(xxx|yyy|zzz)/.*$ {
        #do nothing
    }`
but it is not working, either i get a 404 error or a loop

Comment: my link that doesn't help me in the doc http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score -1):

The only solution i found as Nginx is a proxy is making Apache handling the redirect on its side.

so, 
a. nginx 80 is redirecting to nginx 443 specific folders.
b. all https is redirect by nginx 443 to apache 443, and then in apache 443 conf i do a test, if it the specific folders, i stop, and otherwise i redirect to nginx 80.

It's working, but i'm sure it is possible to make nginx handle it and avoid this 1 loop. if someone as a beautiful answer :-)